# Error 404 on flask

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

When I run the server.py which is hosted on 127.0.0.1:5000 it generates the list of articles

```
@app.route("/")
def articles():
    """Show a list of article titles"""
    return render_template('articles.html', my_list= Alist)
```

The code above generates the list of articles and is running properly when I run 127.0.0.1:5000, the list is displayed.

```
@app.route("/article/<topic>/<filename>")
def article(topic,filename):
    """
    Show an article with relative path filename. Assumes the BBC structure of
    topic/filename.txt so our URLs follow that.
    """
    for art in articles_table:
        if art[0]== "%s/%s" %(topic, filename):
            title_str = art[1]
            text_list = art[2].split('\n')
            text_list = [t.lower() for t in text_list if len(t) >= 1]
            rec = recommended(art[0], articles_table, 5)
            break

   return render_template('article.html', title=title_str, text=text_list, 
fiveA= rec)
```

However, whenever I click on any of the articles it redirects to http://127.0.0.1:5000/article/data/bbc/business/003.txt
and generates error 404 but the file is present at a particular path in the local directory
I believe the error is in the 2nd code snippet.
I'm a beginner to flask so I'm really confused as to what to do. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I think that maybe is your identantion order...maybe it is taking your for and return instruction outside or your article function...try fixing that

Comment: But if it there was an indentation error, it wouldn't have run in the first place

Comment: Nope https://repl.it/repls/HilariousAppropriateMap

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to catch the `topic` and the `filename` in the route. The problem is the URL you're trying to access doesn't match the route you have defined.

You have 2 options:

- Change the link so the URL is http://127.0.0.1:5000/article/business/003.txt. By doing this you'll be able to keep the same route you currently have `@app.route("/article/<topic>/<filename>")`. Here `topic`will have the value of `"business"` and `filename` will have the value of `"003.txt"`.
- Or you can leave the link so the URL stays the same (http://127.0.0.1:5000/article/data/bbc/business/003.txt) and you can change your route to look like this: `@app.route("/article/data/bbc/<topic>/<filename>")`. Again `topic` will have the value of `"business"` and `filename` will have the value of `"003.txt"`.

You can find more information about routes [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)

Comment: Glad to help @SrijanGoyal